# Tips when moving from YUI Datatable to Jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, yui, datatables

I thus far used YUI Datatable to render all my records...
 Since Jquery is very popular nowdays and a lightweighter one than YUi, I've decided to use it...

- What are the Learning curves when moving from YUI
  to jquery?
- Tips and tricks about Jquery Datatable?
- Can I configure paginator in jquery datatable?

Comment: If the code works, and you're not planning to change it very often in the future (ie, it's stable) then don't switch to jQuery. Keep it working, and use jQuery for your next project :P

Comment: @Andreas ya i am planning it to use it in my next project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learning curve: You should find that jQuery may be simpler than YUI. It really depends on what you are trying to do. That is, how complex are the tables and the processing that you require. At its simplest the jQuery datatable only needs a single line of code to create. Since you are already familiar with YUI I do not see any problem that you will have with jQuery.

And yes you can configure the paginator in jQuery datatable.

Comment: Reigel has posted an answer with a link to the main site on which you will find many exmaples. It is a very well documented plugin. You will also find custom paging examples.

Answer (score 2):

Tips and tricks about Jquery Datatable?

Try [datatables.net](http://datatables.net)

I have used it and it's very configurable, easy to use.
There are also lots of [examples](http://datatables.net/examples/) in their site.